# What is the effect of antibiotic chloramphenicol on bacterial size?

Tags: bacteriology, antibiotics

When low amounts of antibiotics like Chloramphenicol is added in a bacterial culture, the steady-state growth rate decreases but what happens to the steady-state size? Can anybody please refer me to any paper that comments about the effect of these antibiotics on the size of bacteria (or yeast)?

Comment: There's [this](http://jcs.biologists.org/content/4/3/627.full.pdf), but it's about a protist.

Comment: Thanks @canadianer for the prompt reply. It will be very helpful if I could get some references for bacteria/yeast as well.

Comment: Please can somebody help urgently? Thanks